# как сохранить кадры на диск полученные помощью AVIReader Class - AForge.NET Framework

Tags: c#

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сохранить на диск кадры полученные с помощью  [AForge.NET Framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/db74ba51-28a0-013f-5cbb-98227b0491d7.htm)

вот код

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using AForge.Video.VFW;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
            reader.Open("test.avi");
            while (reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length)
            {
                Bitmap image = reader.GetNextFrame();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При чем тут вообще `AForge`? `image.Save("filepath.bmp");` Читать [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: спс......................

Comment: а если весь ролик ? получится ли с помощью этой функции слить весь ролик покадрово на диск?

Comment: ...откуда слить? у вас и так этот ролик есть

Comment: я имею ввиду разложить на кадры.

Comment: пробовал с помощью цикла но что-то не получилось

Comment: ...что значит не получилось?

Comment: не получается Start < reader.Length переписать так что бы сохранялся не последний а с первого и по ... например последний.